# AzerothCore - Value (ON) of "SCRIPTS" Variable is Invalid

Tags: cmake, azerothcore

I've run into an issue after trying to pull / merge updates from GitHub. In the past I just followed the directions for keeping the server up-to-date on the AzerothCore wiki without issue, but I tried to update recently and I ran into the following error after trying to run CMake:

CMake version: 3.21.1
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
CMake Error at conf/dist/config.cmake:28 (message):
The value (ON) of your SCRIPTS variable is invalid! Allowed values are:
none;static;dynamic;minimal-static;minimal-dynamic.  Set static
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:51 (include)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "G:/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "G:/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

I think that there was a major update to how AC works since I last did a pull / merge on GitHub, and judging by the error it seems like there's something set to "on" when it should be "static," I think. I looked around the config file and found something labeled "CSCRIPTS=${CSCRIPTS:-ON}" and thought maybe I could just change "on" to "static," but that did not do anything, so I changed it back to on.

I checked out the error logs, and it references the following C1083 error:

Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: G:/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):G:/Visual Studio/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_e2a2b.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+5e4b48a27 for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29914 for x64

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

CheckIncludeFile.c

cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR="Debug"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_e2a2b.dir\Debug\" /Fd"cmTC_e2a2b.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue G:\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c

G:\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [G:\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_e2a2b.vcxproj]

I searched around Google for information on pthread.h, and came across this thread:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/76739/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-39pthre.html

I'm incredibly inexperienced so please forgive my ignorance, but while it references the same error, I feel like the answer to my problem has to be related to a variable labeled scripts somewhere but I just can't seem to find it, and it seems like that user's issue is coming from Visual Studio and not CMake, so I am uncertain if the proposed solution of running "vcpkg.exe" as suggested would resolve the issue.

Thank you for your time, please let me know if I need to add any additional information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I found the script variable I was looking for by going to G: > AzerothCore > conf > dist > config.cmake, and changed the value in Scripts and Modules from "-1" to "-static."

I also changed the values of all the "scripts" values in CMake under the Scripts section from default to static, but doing that by itself did nothing, so that might not have been necessary, I think what did the trick was directly changing those two "1's" to "static" in the config.cmake file.